# What are the best ways to protect private keys in code developed for the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, key, private

I have a desktop application written for the .NET framework using C#. To protect some sensitive data, the encryption is used in any data storing. How can I protect the private key?

Someone suggests to store the private keys in the cloud and to retrieve them when needed. Is that the best way to do it for now in .NET framework, or there are some better alternative ways?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: The following resource may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows

Comment: You can't. Anything you do on a client machine can be seen by an admin with debugging rights, and potentially abused by reverse compilation etc. The only safe method is to move the actual decryption or whatever to the cloud and serve it over a webserver.